# Location tracking in react native even if app is closed or in background

Tags: android, react-native

I have to send location data in every 10 minute to the server. That should be work even app is closed or in background. I google some plugins which are as follow.

1.react-native-background-geolocation (paid for android)
2.react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation (will not work when app is killed)

Is it possible to have the requirement done while working with react native.

1. when app is in foreground
2. when app is in background
3. when app is killed

Comment: Do you known how to create a native module on android on react-native ?

Comment: Hmm, I am not familiar with the java

Comment: well you can always create custom module and use Android's background service with alarm timer to run every 10 minutes. I say you buy the paid module

Comment: Have you tried https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html ? It supports background geolocation tracking and comes out-of-the-box (fewer features than the plugins you mentioned, but free and works with CRNA).

Comment: @Carlos did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @Carlos what is your solution for this now?

Comment: I used paid plugin from https://www.transistorsoft.com/shop/products/react-native-background-geolocation
It works fine for me

Comment: Is any free plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like using https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location. The package works great on iOS but, unfortunately, on Android, the tracking does not continue to work properly in the background as you describe. There is actually an open issue about it for that project (https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location/issues/133). In the comments you'll find links to a couple of demo apps / example projects, including one that I put together based on some other examples. In your case, since you only need updates every 10 minutes, you could use: https://github.com/comoser/rn-background-location which has great Android support, runs in a "Background Service" and is configurable down to a minimum of 1 minutes intervals. In my case, I needed more frequent updates since I am developing a fitness / run tracking app, so I wanted to get updates as fast a once per second. In that case, I use a "Foreground Service" on Android which will also display an "Ongoing Notification" to the user, letting them know the app is tracking their location in the "background" (while the app is closed or the screen is off). You can find my foreground service example project here: https://github.com/andersryanc/ReactNative-LocationSample. There are a number of Android specific code adjustments you will need to make in either case. It's not ready yet, but in the near future I plan to update my repo's readme with a detailed set of instructions for implementing the necessary changes in your project.